# Can a #define be assigned the result of defined?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, standards

Is the result of the following code defined in C or C++?

```
#define FOO
#define BAR defined(FOO)
#if BAR
    int x = 1;
#else
    int x = 2;
#endif
```

Comment: Note that this works differently to the solution in the answer (the ifdef-define approach). Yours is late-bound, meaning that `BAR` could expand to different things in different parts of the code depending on where `FOO` is defined. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37e940a76f0fa896

Comment: Eww, I take that back. I hope this is one of the things addressed by the people trying to lower UB in the preprocessor, because this is rather unintuitive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `defined` as an expansion in conditional directive is considered as **Undefined Behavior**.

- **From C99 Standard: 6.10.1/4** | [**C++11 Standard Last Working Draft(n4296) 16.1/4**](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4296.pdf)

> **If the token `defined` is generated as a result of this replacement
>   process** or use of the `defined` unary operator does not match one of the
>   two specified forms prior to macro replacement, **the behavior is
>   undefined.**

- **From C99 Standard: 6.10.8/4** | [**C++11 Standard Last Working Draft(n4296) 16.8/4**](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4296.pdf)

> None of these macro names, **nor the identifier `defined`**, **shall be the
>   subject of a `#define` or a `#undef` preprocessing directive**.

- [**GNU - CPP 4.2.3**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html)

> **If the `defined` operator appears as a result of a macro expansion, the
>   C standard says the behavior is undefined**. GNU cpp treats it as a
>   genuine defined operator and evaluates it normally. It will warn
>   wherever your code uses this feature if you use the command-line
>   option ‘-pedantic’, since other compilers may handle it differently.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a source for that quote?

Comment: I'd suggest giving the reference from the standard first, as that is definitive.  The behaviour for a particular implementation is not.   (i.e. the standard is the basis for assessing correctness of a compiler/preprocessor, not the reverse).